# Unable to start Oracle Database Server : Get an error as I try to start it

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, windows, oracle-11g

I just installed [Oracle Database Express Edition 11g Release 2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/express-edition/overview/index.html) for windows.It created a short cut icon on the desktop :

[image]

but as I click this icon I see this dialog box :

[image]

What is it ? How do I start my Oracle Database Server ?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the instructions on how to start the database:
[Starting Oracle Database XE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18803/toc.htm#XEINW133)

Normally you first need to start the database and then you can access it with that link. I don't remember if the database is started after you do the installation.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a small installer bug.

Edit that path and replace the `%HTTPPORT%` with `8080` or the port you chose if you modified the default.

Comment: I didn't modify a thing.How do I edit the path now ?

Comment: Right click -> Properties on the icon. It's just a shortcut.

Comment: [Didn't understand how !](http://i45.tinypic.com/2yydqih.jpg)

Comment: Did you try editing the target file?

Comment: `E:\Installed_Apps\Oracle_11g_ExEdition\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\Get_Started.url` this path gets me `Get_Started.html` shortcut. And as I open it I see [this](http://i45.tinypic.com/kafrpi.jpg)

Comment: Well, you're done.

Comment: but I did nothing !